# Multiple typography treatments in one sentence?

Tags: html, css, typography

I was wondering if its possible to set multiple type treatments in one sentence?
For example, a sentence may be set to size:14, but two letters are size:10.

I'm mainly using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used spans?

E.g.

```
<p>Hello <span>world</span>.</p>
```

You can style it using CSS like this:

```
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

p span {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Words that are marked as <span> begin a new layer of text.

Comment: Are you styling `span` anywhere else in your CSS? Make sure you are not doing anything like `display: block;`

Comment: The thing is I'm using Cargo Collective as a platform for my website. That being said, there are a TON of "Span" stuff. Perhaps you know other methods?

Comment: If putting a simple span in there is breaking up your sentence, then the template you are using is fubar. Im not sure how to help further, sorry.

Comment: @kenhimself: Use a class (e.g., `<span class="foo"></span>`) and **overwrite** the styles the `span` got in the CSS (e.g., `.foo {display:inline;}`).